# Why is this condition not satisfied?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements

i hope you can help me :)
i want to get a string of font file path from sharedpreferences, and if there isnt any string load the default font in assets, okay. the problem comes when i try to stablish the condition, see it here:

```
 String filePath = new String(preferences.getString(String.valueOf(v.getId()+"font"),"default"));
    Log.d("","choosed font: "+filePath);

    if (filePath == "default"){
        v.setTypeface((Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Default.ttf")),preferencias.getInt(String.valueOf(v.getId()+"style"), 0));
    }else{
        v.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromFile(filePath),preferencias.getInt(String.valueOf(v.getId()+"style"), 0)); 
    }
```

as you can see, the program would load default font if filePath = default, but the program always executes the order inside "else"...

the order to make log appear shows clearly: chosen font: default. because i have never putString

so why is this condition not satisfied??

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1285418) might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare `String` using `equals()`

```
if (filePath.equals("default"))
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) for more information.

`==` compares references,not the values. In your case, you want to check for the value equality, not the reference equality.

Comment: @BamsBamx no. Not you. Someone has downvoted the answer. I wanted to know the reason, incase I missed something. :-)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
filePath.equals("default")
```

instead of

```
if (filePath == "default")
```

Answer (score 2):

`==` checks if the reference is same.

`.equals` check the value

Answer (score 1):

Do not just use this:
**This compares references, not values!**

```
if (filePath == "default")
```

always use `equals(...)` for Strings!

```
if (filePath.equals("default"))
```

Corrected version of your code:

```
 String filePath = new String(preferences.getString(String.valueOf(v.getId()+"font"),"default"));
    Log.d("","choosed font: "+filePath);

    if (filePath.equals("default")){
        v.setTypeface((Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Default.ttf")),preferencias.getInt(String.valueOf(v.getId()+"style"), 0));
    }else{
        v.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromFile(filePath),preferencias.getInt(String.valueOf(v.getId()+"style"), 0)); 
    }
```

Explanation: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

> Compares values for equality. Because this method is defined in the
>   Object class, from which all other classes are derived, it's
>   automatically defined for every class. However, it doesn't perform an
>   intelligent comparison for most classes unless the class overrides it.
>   It has been defined in a meaningful way for most Java core classes. If
>   it's not defined for a (user) class, it behaves the same as ==.

Answer (score 0):

use this to avoid NullPointerException if filePath is null

```
if ("default".equals(filePath ))
```

Comment: What if that is the desired behaviour?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. If you want always avoid NPE you should use this construction, if your reference can be null and this a part of your logic you can use usual construction and catch exception.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (filePath.equals("default"))
```